# Flickering HttpClient sometimes throwing IOException

Tags: java-http-client, java-19

I'm using `java.net.http.HttpClient.newHttpClient()` under Java 19 (Temurin) and perform `sendAsync(...)` requests from different treads on the same instance. I assume this is ok, as the javadoc states:

> Once built, an HttpClient is immutable...

However, *some* requests fail with:

```
java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 header parser received no bytes
```

The weird thing is, it depends on the speed of my requests:

- Requests every 5 seconds: 30% failure
- Requests every 3 seconds: 0% failure

I've written a test for it:

```
private final HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create("https://..."))
    .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray("[]".getBytes()))
    .build();

@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(ints = {3, 5})
void httpClientTest(int intervalSeconds) throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray()).get();
    Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(intervalSeconds));
    httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray()).get();
    Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(intervalSeconds));
    httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray()).get();
    Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(intervalSeconds));
    httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray()).get();
    Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(intervalSeconds));
    httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray()).get();
}
```

I've already tried the following:

- Doing the same with `curl` on the command line. No requests fail whatever interval I try. So it's probably not a problem with the server.
- Running the tests multiple times in parallel. Still the 5-second-intervals fail (then multiple times in parallel). So it's probably not a problem with the server.
- Creating an `HttpClient.newHttpClient()` for every request. No requests fail whatever interval. So it's probably not a problem with the server but with an internal state of the `HttpClient` (although it claims to be immutable?).

Do you have an idea what I could do, without needing to create a new `HttpClient` for every request?

Comment: I would suspect that this is due to the server closing the (idle) connection at the same time that the client tries to reuse it. I assume what you observe is mostly for HTTP/1.1 requests? It should be possible to configure the keepalive time of HTTP/1.1 connections on the client side using: `-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=duration-in-seconds` - try setting it to `-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=3` and it may solve your problem.

Comment: Wow, I would never have thought about that. This was it! Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer for the record: the `java.net.HttpClient` has a long default HTTP/1.1 keepAlive time, which is longer than what usual servers are configured with. This often results in the server closing idle HTTP/1.1 connections before the client does. If the server closes the connection at about the same time than the client tries to reuse it, some `IOException` might get raised.

If such exceptions are observed too frequently applications should consider adapting the default keepAlive time in the client to some value shorter than what the servers it connects to are using.
A default value for the HttpClient HTTP/1.1 keepAlive time can be [specified on the command line](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/core/java-networking.html#GUID-86B96A42-74FE-4E7D-8E60-D64A03862083) with: `-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=duration-in-seconds`

So for instance - if a server is configured with a keepAlive time of 5s, you could consider supplying `-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=3` or `-Djdk.httpclient.keepalive.timeout=4` on the client's java command line.

Answer (score 2):

For additional records, if anybody looks informations about this error :

- Setting http version `1.1` in the builder may not solve your issue : in [the HttpClient Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.Version.html), it is said that it is the **prefered** version, and that it may not be the one used :

> For example, if HTTP/2 is requested through a proxy, and if the implementation does not support this mode, then HTTP/1.1 may be used

- If you want to debug what is happening inside the http client, you can use the following system property : `Djdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log=all`.
  With that, you will be able to see when the connection is closed by the distant server.

Answer (score 0):

Not scientifically proven but as one "to try and see" for problem connections you can try to persuade the protocol to clearly favour one version or another over negotiation or whatever under-the-hood stuff is triggering this grief. E.g.., here's the example which has helped in our case:

```
        // The server receiving the HTTP request must not support HTTP 2, so we have to explicitly set the version in the request to 1.1
        val httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build()
```